# scala, Passing an operator as argument of a function

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
for( i <- 0 to 8){
  ((numbers(i) - i)/3).abs + ((numbers(i) - i)%3).abs
}
```

and I would like to do, as the title says, something like this

```
for( i <- 0 to 8){
  by3(numbers(i), i, /) + by3(numbers(i), i, %)
}

def by3(a: Int, b: Int, op: Int => Int) = ((a - b) op 3).abs
```

and probably also use a partially applied function for it.. but by now this would be possible to achieve? How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get rid of the underscores you need to define the functions as values.

```
val / = (a:Int, b: Int) => a / b
val % = (a:Int, b: Int) => a % b

def by3(a: Int, b: Int, fn: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = fn(a - b, 3).abs

(0 to 8).foreach(i => by3(numbers(i), i, /) + by3(numbers(i), i, %))
```

Comment: cool from the point of view of how flexible the language is, but quite obscure from a code maintainability perspective. I wouldn't let this get into the codebase.

Answer (score 18):

First, you need to correctly define `op` as a function (specifically, a `Function2`)

`def operate(a: Int, b: Int, op: (Int, Int) => Int ) : Int = (op ((a - b), 3)).abs`

Operators in Scala are actually methods: + is a method of Int(and Long, Double, ...)  in Scala OO foundation. Then, to pass a operator (method) as a function, you can lift it using the underscore notation: 
`operate(5, 3, _ + _)`

Answer (score 6):

*Edited/Update:*

Being concise, the shortest way to do it is:

`def doStuff(a: Int, b: Int, op: (Int, Int) => Int) = {op(a - b, 3).abs}`

`doStuff(4,1,_%_)`

So you can `doStuff(numbers(i), i, _ / _) + doStuff(numbers(i), i, _ % _)`

Comment: just one thing - this is really verbose. I was searching for some little function to not duplicate a lot of charachters just for one operator, and knowing scala i was almost sure i could pass in the function just % or /. This is actually a half reply to my question, I was searching for a method to pass in an operator directly, not create two wrapper functions.

Comment: Oh, I did edit the answer and then noticed that @maasg already posted the solution. Sorry for the buzz.

Comment: I would like to point out, that although your solution was nice, is not what I was asking. Or at least, as I said, it was half the solution. I called it "verbose" not because of the explanation, but because of the length of the code. The explanation was nice :)