# Operators as function literals

Tags: scala

So for a very small formula interpretter someone asked me to code-golf, I wanted to do something like

```
  val ops = Map("plus" -> + , "minus"-> -, "times"-> *, "div" -> / )
```

to allow quick conversion between keywords and the functions they describe.  Not only did this syntax not parse, but none of the other shorthand syntaxes I tried ( `_ + _`, `_:Int.+_`)parsed.  Is there a way of doing this as a function shorthand, or am I doomed to writing out the lambdas fully, ruining my golf score.

Edit: The problem in question was integers only.  I understand that overloading would make this vastly more difficult otherwise.

Comment: The only way I know would be `val ops = Map[String, (Int, Int) => Int]("plus" -> (_ + _), "minus" -> (_ - _));` That doesn't save too many characters though... I'm curious what more experienced/smarter people will suggest. :)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek if the OP wants a general aproach for any value, lambda won't help, cause this operations are overloaded

Comment: @AlexIv True, it's specialized. I assumed by the `_:Int` annotation in the question that a simple `(Int, Int) => Int` will be sufficient. If it's a general question then I'm out of ideas. :)

Comment: The only way i can think of is a typeclass with defining `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` as objects with `apply` method and implicit typeclass

Comment: Interesting! In Haskell this would be simply `ops "plus" = (+); ops "times" = (*)` etc.

Comment: @AlexIv Typeclasses certainly look clean. Maybe not short and/or terse for such a simple application, but clean...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek if the OP wants such functionality only for an Int, then just an object should do the trick: `object + { def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b }`, then with an implicit make it an infix operation

Comment: see also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552430/scala-passing-an-operator-as-argument-of-a-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how your score is impacted by defining an additional function. You could lift the operators, using something like this:

```
def lift(f:(Int,Int)=>Int) = f
val ops = Map("plus" -> lift(_+_), "minus" -> lift(_-_), "times"-> lift(_*_), "div" -> lift(_/_))
```

And if you want to shave some chars:

```
def  ↑(f:(Int,Int)=>Int) = f
val ops = Map("plus" -> ↑(_+_), "minus" -> ↑(_-_), "times"-> ↑(_*_), "div" -> ↑(_/_))
```

And as om-nom-nom comments, this explicit lifting can be done by the compiler as well by providing the type signature to coerse the lifting:

```
val ops: Map[String, (Int,Int) => Int] = Map("plus" -> (_+_), "minus" -> (_-_), "times"->(_*_), "div" -> (_/_))
```

Comment: Isn't much better than `val ops: Map[String, (Int,Int) => Int] = Map("plus" -> (_+_), "minus" -> {_-_}, "times"-> {_*_}, "div" -> {_/_})` (either () or {} braces)

Comment: @om-nom-nom yeah, I was driving back home thinking... method lifting is done automatically by the compiler and realized that it only needed the type signature.